# How to use MockedProvider for dependent queries being used with compose HOC?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, react-apollo

I want to test a React component that consumes 3 queries by way of HOC. Variable of third query is set from data returned from first query. Third query shows loading state but does not return data.

I am using skip config on third query to prevent it from running until first query finish loading data. Everything works if I dont use skip and set variable to a constant value. When I use skip, It shows me loading = true for third query after getting data from first query but it does not loads data. Given below sample code. Here withIgnoreQuery is dependent on withSelectedQuery:

```
const withSelectedQuery = graphql(HOME_SCREEN_QUERY, {
  name: 'selectedQueryData',
  options: ownProps => {        
    return { variables: { screenId: '1' } }
  },
  props: ({ selectedQueryData, ownProps }) => {        
    return { selectedQueryData, ...ownProps }
  }
})
const withIgnoreQuery = graphql(GET_IGNORE_LIST_QUERY, {
  name: 'ignoreListData',
  options: ownProps => {

    if (
      !!ownProps.selectedQueryData &&
      !!ownProps.selectedQueryData.userdata
    ) {


      return {
        variables: {
          id: '4e3d44c1-ec50-40c3-8783-1983a905a8a9'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  props: ({ ignoreListData, ownProps }) => {

    return { ignoreListData, ...ownProps }
  },
  skip: props => {

    return !!props.selectedQueryData &&
      !!props.selectedQueryData.userdata
      ? false
      : true
  }
})
const withListQuery = graphql(INITIALSTATE_QUERY, {
  name: 'listData',
  options: ownProps => {

    return {
      variables: {
        id: '2534e504-fd44-4513-915c-2037b7f71a42'
      }
    }
  },
  props: ({ listData, ownProps }) => {

    return { listData, ...ownProps }
  }
})
class testingInner extends Component {
  render() {
    let loading, error
    const {
      ignoreListData,
      listData,
      selectedQueryData
    } = this.props

    if (!!selectedQueryData) {
      ;({ loading, error } = selectedQueryData)

      if (loading) {

        return 'Loading..'
      }
      if (error) {

        return `Error! ${error.message}`
      }
    }

    if (!!ignoreListData) {
      ;({ loading, error } = ignoreListData)

      if (loading) {

        return 'Loading..'
      }
      if (error) {

        return `Error! ${error.message}`
      }
    }
    if (!!listData) {
      ;({ loading, error } = listData)

      if (loading) {

        return 'Loading..'
      }
      if (error) {

        return `Error! ${error.message}`
      }
    }
    return <span>reached here</span>
  }
}
const TestingComp = compose(
  withSelectedQuery,
  withListQuery,
  withIgnoreQuery
)(testingInner)

const mock = [
  {
    request: {
      query: HOME_SCREEN_QUERY,
      variables: {
        screenId: '1'
      }
    },
    result: () => {

      return {
        data: {
          homeScreen: {
            id: '1',
            __typename: 'HomeScreenType',
            selectedProductFamily: {
              __typename: 'SelectedFamilyType',
              id: '2534e504-fd44-4513-915c-2037b7f71a42'
            }
          },
          userdata: {
            __typename: 'UserDataType',
            id: '2',
            firm: {
              __typename: 'FirmType',
              id: '4e3d44c1-ec50-40c3-8783-1983a905a8a9'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    request: {
      query: GET_IGNORE_LIST_QUERY,
      variables: {
        id: '4e3d44c1-ec50-40c3-8783-1983a905a8a9'
      }
    },
    result: () => {

      return {
        data: {
          firm: {
            id: '4e3d44c1-ec50-40c3-8783-1983a905a8a9',
            __typename: 'FirmType',
            checklistIgnoreLists: [
              {
                id: '8319bdf5-f5f0-4e1b-9381-9f47a6cbe11d',
                __typename: 'ChecklistIgnoreListType',
                ignoredValues: [
                  'item1',
                  'item2'
                ],
                name: 'IGNORE LIST'
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    request: {
      query: INITIALSTATE_QUERY,
      variables: {
        id: '2534e504-fd44-4513-915c-2037b7f71a42'
      }
    },
    result: () => {

      return {
        data: {
          productFamily: {
            id: '2534e504-fd44-4513-915c-2037b7f71a42',
            __typename: 'ProductFamilyType',
            checklistPreview: {
              __typename: 'ItemPreviewType',
              checklistTags: [
                {
                  __typename: 'ItemTagType',
                  sourceObjectType: 'ItemType',
                  sourceObjectId: 'e9cbd2ba-c1a9-4052-b23e-9bc8a1e626b1',
                  contentItemId: 'fde9fbd9-33c3-47d0-a262-3d9a08b88eb0',
                  optionItemId: null,
                  isTextIgnored: false,
                  text: 'GENERAL',
                  children: [
                    {
                      __typename: 'ItemTagType',
                      sourceObjectType: 'ItemType',
                      sourceObjectId:
                        'de66a6a0-8873-4e51-a629-2bb309b215ef',
                      contentItemId: 'c2474b19-ea8c-406c-ae6f-957a51a4bc10',
                      optionItemId: null,
                      isTextIgnored: false,
                      text: 'item1',
                      children: []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]



const wrapper = renderer.create(
  <MockedProvider
    mocks={mock}
    addTypename={false}>
    <TestingComp />
  </MockedProvider>
)
await wait(0) 

expect(wrapper.toJSON().children).toContain('Loading')
```